# Altair multiple graphs from single data frame

Tags: python, graph, charts, streamlit, altair

My data frame looks like

```
testname| owner| seed| duration| status| module|  date            |
t1      | ram  | 101 | NA      | PASS  | M_1   | 03_01_2023_15_42 |
t2      | ram  | 101 | NA      | PASS  | M_1   | 03_01_2023_15_42 |
t3      | Wong | 101 | NA      | PASS  | M_2   | 03_01_2023_15_42 |
t4      | xin  | 101 | NA      | FAIL  | M_2   | 03_01_2023_15_42 |
t11     | ram  | 101 | NA      | PASS  | M_1   | 03_02_2023_15_42 |
t22     | ram  | 101 | NA      | PASS  | M_1   | 03_02_2023_15_42 |
t33     | Wong | 101 | NA      | PASS  | M_2   | 03_02_2023_15_42 |
t44     | xin  | 101 | NA      | FAIL  | M_2   | 03_02_2023_15_42 |
```

Am trying to create graphs in Altair/Streamlit, were every module is a chart and have dates on x-axis and count of status on y-axis.

Am very new to this, so please bare with me.

I tried the below codes, and weren't successful

```py
base_chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('date:O'),
    alt.Y('count(status):O'),
    color='status'
)
```

Also for multiple graphs from online I found I could use as below

```py
base_chart.encode(y=alt.Y("column1")) | base_chart.encode(y=alt.Y("column2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert `date` column to date time using [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) after that use [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the modules in order to create chart data. Pass that data to a dictionary and finally write every chart from the dictionary.

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M')

charts = {}
for module, module_data in df.groupby('module'):
    count_data = (module_data.groupby(['date', 'status'])
                             .size().reset_index(name='count'))

    chart = alt.Chart(count_data).mark_bar().encode(
        x=alt.X('date:T', title='Date'),
        y=alt.Y('count:Q', title='Count'),
        color=alt.Color('status:N', title='Status'),
        tooltip=['date:T', 'status:N', 'count:Q']
    ).properties(
        width=500,
        height=300,
        title=f'Module {module}'
    )
    charts[module] = chart

for module, chart in charts.items():
    st.write(chart)
```

You can also chose to unpack the charts instead of using a traditional for loop to write a chart at a time. If ever needed, the last for loop can be re-written as:

```py
module, chart = zip(*charts.items())
st.write(*chart)
```

Here is a reference of [`altair.Chart doc`](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/toplevel/altair.Chart.html) to better understand how some of the parameters are used in the code snippet.